# Running QTP Scripts on a Remote Machine (Windows 7)

Tags: qtp

I want to run the QTP script that resides in my machine from another Machine in  the  LAN.

Tried doing the following:

DCOM Configuration is done (on the machine where the script has to be run)

Script resides in the Script Initiator machine:

```
   dim qapp
   set qapp = createobject("QuickTest.Application","<IP Address")
   qapp.launch
   qapp.visible = true
```

Please Help..

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? what is the error you get?

Comment: Getting the below error while executing the code to launch QTP in the remote machine 
"Permission Denied 'createobject'"
Code:800A0046

Comment: I see...what did you do as part of 'DCOM Configuration'?

Comment: Yes... well let me detail it... DCOM configuration is done in the Remote Machine
Given the required permissions to the controller machine (machine from where the execution is been triggered)
When I am trying to run the above code in the controller machine, Getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I would first ensure that below script works fine in the machine (without IP address. Just directly try to run this in the remote machine. It should launch QTP/UFT)

```
dim qapp
set qapp = createobject("QuickTest.Application")
qapp.launch
qapp.visible = true
```

2) **DCOM settings:**

- QuickTest Professional Automation
- HP Unified Functional Testing

In DCOM properties for the above applications, under **Security** tab, give required permissions. I have given full permissions for all users.
Under **Identity** tab, Select '**Interactive User**'.

3) **User Permissions:**

You must have the following file system permissions:

```
➤ Full read and write permissions for all the files and folders under the folder in which QuickTest is installed
➤ Full read and write permissions to the Temp folder
➤ Read permissions to the Windows folder and to the System folder
```

You must have the following registry key permissions:

```
➤ Full read and write permissions to all the keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive
➤ Read and Query Value permissions to all the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT keys
```

Comment: For me the script is working without IP address. Even though the above mentioned DCOM settings are done, it's giving permission denied error.

Comment: An update from my side: When I am loggin to both controller (machine from which the execution is trigerred) and slave (remote machine) with same ID it is working.

Comment: Did you login as the user (for whom you get the permission denied error) in the machine and run QTP? Does it work? QTP might need admin privileges. UAC is disabled?

Comment: In the remote machine I logged in with controller user ID, I could launch UFT manually & programmatically and execute the script as well.
(But that user don't have admin privilege on the remote machine.)

Comment: Got the admin access for the remote machine. It resolved the issue. Able to execute the scripts in the Remote machine (not using the same user login). Thanks a lot...

Comment: I have one more query regarding the Remote Execution:
Post the execution, Is it possible get the Progress & status to the controller machine?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. QTApp.Test.Run qtResultsO, FALSE, testParams  

FALSE makes the test to be executed in async mode. You can access the results & environment variables etc.

I am using Jenkins for the past 2 years to run my QTP scripts in the remote machines. IT IS AWESOME.  Check this. http://studyautomation.com/ci-uft-uft-integration-jenkins/