# Running QTP on a remote computer

Tags: windows, selenium, ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft

I have the following line of code in my Local computer. It opens word file.

```
    Dim qtApp
    Set qtApp =CreateObject("QuickTest.Application",")
    SystemUtil.Run "WINWORD"
```

Now I used the following line of code on my local computer so that the code runs on my remote computer.

```
 Dim qtApp
 Set qtApp =CreateObject("QuickTest.Application","remote computer ip address")
 SystemUtil.Run "WINWORD"
```

Now when I hit run button from UFT in my local computer I am presented with the following error:

```
ActiveX component can't create object: 'QuickTest.Application'.
Line (2): "Set qtApp =CreateObject("QuickTest.Application","172.16.136.103")"
```

What have I done wrong? I have followed this tutorial : http://www.qtpsudhakar.com/2009/07/executing-qtp-scripts-on-remote.html

Note : QTP is added and installed on local and remote computers. The license type is seat license. I am using 30 day trial full version of HP Unified Functional Testing 12.52 build 6851.

Answer (score 1):

Does the below statement work fine if you try to directly execute in the remote machine?

```
Dim qtApp
Set qtApp =CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
```

If it does not work, you might have to re-install QTP/UFT in the machine.

Also you might have to give permission in the DCOM settings.

[Running QTP Scripts on a Remote Machine (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441643/running-qtp-scripts-on-a-remote-machine-windows-7)

---

Using VBScript to launch QTP in the remote machine is old school approach.

Start using jenkins if possible.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/executing-qtpuft-scripts-using-jenkins/

Comment: I tried to run the code suggested in my remote machine and the code works. The only problem is I am not able to run it remotely. I have also given permission in the DCOM settings. I have added permission to everyone in my domain.

Comment: Did you check everything in the post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441643/running-qtp-scripts-on-a-remote-machine-windows-7

Comment: As i had said, you should consider jenkins. It is FREE and fun.

Comment: QTP might need admin privileges. Ensure that you have enough access in the remote as well. Ensure UAC is disabled.

Comment: Ok I will check Jenkins. Should jenkins needs to installed on both master and remote computer ?

Comment: Only master. It is web based. Slave should be connected to master via jnlp. It will be registered as a windows service. Even if u restart slave, it will automatically connect to master.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to run it on Atlassian Bamboo?